# Get current username in a blank php page (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I searched the Stack Overflow website to get a proper answer (that works) but unfortunately nothing worked...

It's a simple question, I just need to output the current users username!

I found a code on stackoverflow which is the following:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo "ID User : ".$user_id ;
if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
} else {
    echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
}
?>
```

^^found it on this site

When I do this I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_user_id() in
>   /home/heal/public_html/mysite.com/index.php on line 14

I'm using wordpress version 3.3.1

Comment: Did you load up the wordpress libraries before trying this? Just because wordpress is installed doesn't mean you can just start calling WP functions inside any joe-random PHP script.

Comment: Where in the code are have you tried adding this snippit? Have the requisite wp libraries been loaded ahead of it? Try providing the whole script, which should make it easier to figure this out.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to access global variables and for that you need to load wordpress in your new page.

```
if ( !defined('__DIR__') ) define('__DIR__', dirname(__FILE__)); //getting current directory using magic constants __DIR__ is deprecated in php 5.3.+
$path = explode('wp-content',__DIR__); //getting main web root path for including further files.
include_once($path[0].'wp-load.php'); //for getting global variables like wpdb 
    global $current_user;

    echo $current_user->user_login;
```

After adding above you can now access global variables. user_login will print username. I hope that helps you. Also i agree with @j3frea. Here i have shown you the hint in which i was trying to implement plugin,so i exploded it using 'wp-content'.

Answer (score 2):

At http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

It suggests that you're looking for `$current_user->user_login`

Their default example is:

```
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

I must admit though, if you're getting `Call to undefined function get_current_user_id()` then it's more likely that wordpress is not correctly installed or something of that nature.

I wonder why you are editing `index.php` -> wordpress does the frontend stuff for you, perhaps you should be looking at theming.

Comment: I get the same error again....he doesn't recoginze that function! :(
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo() in /home/heal/public_html/mysite.com/index.php on line 16

Comment: Okay, why are you editing index.php? - it seems likely that it's something to do with theming...

Comment: I'm working on index2.php, I changed the name for you guys :p
Not editing index.php or I will ruin everything :p

Comment: could you guys make one for me? :D

Comment: Okay - this is why people are moaning at you in the comments "Did you load up the wordpress libraries before trying this?" - this is not how wordpress works. You need to write a plugin or a theme to use wordpress functionality. Check their documentation section for info on how to do that... (http://codex.wordpress.org/)